# optimize the query which results the duplicates taken from two diff data tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

```
select 
       A.SlNo 
      ,A.[Company Code]
      ,A.[Document Number]
      ,A.[Document Type]
      ,CONVERT(varchar(10),A.[Document Date],101) AS [Document Date]
      ,A.[Reference]
      ,CAST(Null as nvarchar(5)) As NumericInvoice
      ,CONVERT(varchar(10),A.[Posting Date],101) AS [Posting Date]
      ,A.[Clearing Document]
      ,A.[Amount in doc# curr#]`enter code here`
      ,A.[Document currency]
      ,A.[Account]
      ,A.[Account Description]
      ,A.[User Name]
      ,A.dumptype
      ,CAST(Null As Varchar(5)) As Similarity
      ,CASE
       When (A.[Reference] = B.[Reference] and A.[Amount in doc# curr#]= B.[Amount in doc# curr#]) then 'DUPEPAYA'
       END  As [Status]
      ,CAST(Null As Varchar(5)) As [DupeSets]
 from MasterData A
 Join  InputData B  on (A.[Reference] = B.[Reference] and A.[Amount in doc# curr#]= B.[Amount in doc# curr#])


Union All 

select distinct
       A.SlNo 
      ,A.[Company Code]
      ,A.[Document Number]
      ,A.[Document Type]
      ,CONVERT(varchar(10),A.[Document Date],101) AS [Document Date]
      ,A.[Reference]
      ,CAST(Null as nvarchar(5)) As NumericInvoice
      ,CONVERT(varchar(10),A.[Posting Date],101) AS [Posting Date]
      ,A.[Clearing Document]
      ,A.[Amount in doc# curr#]
      ,A.[Document currency]
      ,A.[Account]
      ,A.[Account Description]
      ,A.[User Name]
      ,A.dumptype
      ,CAST(Null As Varchar(5)) As Similarity
      ,CASE
       When (A.[Reference] = B.[Reference] and A.[Amount in doc# curr#]= B.[Amount in doc# curr#]) then 'DUPEPAYA'
       END  As [Status]
      ,DENSE_Rank () Over (order by A.[Reference], A.[Account Description], A.dumptype asc) As [DupeSets]
from InputData A
Join  MasterData B  on (A.[Reference] = B.[Reference] and A.[Amount in doc# curr#]= B.[Amount in doc# curr#])

order by A.[Reference], A.[Account Description], A.dumptype asc
```

I want to optimize the above query which results in the duplicates from masterdata table to that of the input data table on few validations, these data tables deal with a huge amount of data hence taking a long time to execute the query. please help 
Note: I'm a beginner in SQL.

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: Do both tables have good indexes for this query to take advantage of?

Comment: Did you check the Estimated execution plan? https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-optimize-sql-server-query-performance/

Comment: Why do you have to query 2 tables twice in reverse order?  It doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: @alexherm those two tables are two different, input n master tables with same columns, please help me with any alternative, as i have mentioned that im new to sql.